# Obtaining a list of class names with objc_getClassList in JavaScript for Automation

Tags: objective-c, javascript-automation

By using `ObjC.bindFunction` in JXA, we can obtain an integer result from `objc_getClassList`.

Does anyone understand the types and bridging issues well enough to find a route to getting a list of class name strings returned by `objc_getClassList` into the JavaScript for Automation JSContext ?

(The code below returns only an `[Object Ref]` string)

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    ObjC.import('stdlib');


    ObjC.bindFunction('CFMakeCollectable', [ 'id', [ 'void *' ] ]);

    ObjC.bindFunction('objc_getClassList', ['int', ['void *', 'int']]);

    var classes = Ref();

    const intClasses = $.objc_getClassList(null, 0);

    $.objc_getClassList(classes, intClasses);

    $.CFMakeCollectable(classes);

    return [intClasses, classes];

    //-> [11411, [object Ref]]

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `objc_getClassList` function is expecting us to provide it with a buffer of memory to copy the class list into.  Normally, JXA would treat the return type of malloc as a C array of unsigned chars, but using `bindFunction` we can cast malloc's return type to a C array of pointers, and make `objc_getClassList`'s first argument match that type. Then, it's just a matter of indexing into the buffer (of type Ref) and passing that value into `class_getName`.

```
ObjC.bindFunction('objc_getClassList', ['int', ['void**', 'int']])
ObjC.bindFunction('malloc', ['void**', ['int']])
ObjC.bindFunction('class_getName', ['char *', ['void*']])

const numClasses = $.objc_getClassList(undefined, 0)
const classes = $.malloc(8*numClasses)
$.objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses)
for (i=0; i<numClasses; i++) {
  console.log("classes[" + i + "]: " + $.class_getName(classes[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both for your code and for your explanation – that's both impressive and incredibly helpful.